# Form validation with jQuery validation and bootstrap confirmation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a form which is validated using the jQuery validation plugin. I added the bootstrap confirmation on the submit button. Everything is working fine, except that I want the bootstrap confirmation to appear on the submit button when the form no longer has any errors.

I've tried doing this:

HTML code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit_button" data-toggle="confirmation"data-popout="true">Submit</button>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#submit_button").on('click', function(){
    if($('#form').valid()) {
        $(this).trigger("confirmation");
    }
});
```

But it didn't do anything. Should I use the submitHandler in jQuery validation? Or is this not just possible?

Comment: change  `button` to `<input  type="button" />` so it doesn't perform it's default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use the submitHandler in jQuery validation?

YES, of course.

Use the `submitHandler` for this.  [As per documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler), it fires only when the form is valid, so there's no need to test the form's validity or use another `click` handler.

```
$('#form').validate({
    // options, etc.
    submitHandler: function(form) { // fires when valid (and on button click)
        $("#selector").trigger("confirmation");
    }
});
```